# How to send "ATA Secure Erase" command to SSD?

Tags: linux, encryption, ssd, disk-encryption, hdparm

A very good way to erase a SSD which have [SED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) support is to [change the password/key](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase). But what to do with those that doesn't have SED support?

[This article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/securely-erase-ssd-without-destroying/) says

> Fortunately it is possible to erase most SSDs, though this is closer
>   to a “reset” than a wipe. The “ATA Secure Erase” command instructs the
>   drive to flush all stored electrons, forcing the drive to “forget” all
>   stored data. This command essentially resets all available blocks to
>   the “erase” state, which is what TRIM uses for garbage collection
>   purposes.

**Question**

I suppose it is something that can be done with `hdparm`, so does anyone know what command that does this?

Comment: It should be noted that there are drives encrypting the content - and they also forget the key, so the data is not only "random" (missing the metadata to reconstruct it), but also encrypted with an unrecoverable key... that allows the SAFE deletion of SSD and hard discs in pretty much milliseconds. Hardware storage encryption is a standard feature today on most enterprise hardware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. See if the feature is not frozen. `hdparm -I /dev/sdX`. If it is (usually by the BIOS), a good way to unfreeze it is to suspend the computer, and resume - then the drive gets powered up, but without BIOS.
2. IMPORTANT: set the password. This will enable the security feature of the drive: `hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass password /dev/sdX`
3. Lastly, erase the drive:`hdparm --user-master u --security-erase password /dev/sdX`

The procedure is described here in more detail:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD_memory_cell_clearing

Example from my drive:

```
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
    not supported: enhanced erase
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
```

So it is frozen... now I suspend... and...

```
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
    not supported: enhanced erase
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
```

Comment: Much better now; +1 from me!

Comment: You have just copy pasted the content of the article I linked to which explains how to change the password/key. That is not what the question is about. Please read OP.

Comment: Well, you asked what do I do  if the drive does not support full drive encryption, and I want to erase it with hdparm.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes I don't understand what you're talking about. This _exactly_ answers the question you asked.

Comment: I am asking for the ATA command that *resets* the SSD, not changing the password/key.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes You need to set a password before you can issue the ATA Secure Erase command. This answer is precisely what you need, unless you have mis-stated your question

Comment: Let's finish the disscussion, shall we? I think everyone has come out of it a little wiser.